# Cómo copiar de una struct a un nuevo vector del mismo tipo en c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, struct

Tengo este codigo y hasta aquí todo bien:

```
struct Personas{
            char  NumSerie[30];
            int Edad;
            char  Sexo;
            float Peso;
  }Persona[100];
```

Capturo los datos para cada persona y los muestro; pero a la hora de realizar otra operacion como copiar desde un miembro de la estructura a nuevo arreglo del mismo tipo no me lo permite; no sé cómo realizar un vector de tipo char o String por que no me permite utilizar punteros y este es lo que he tratado de hacer pero me bota un error, entiendo que me estaria tratando de copiar en cada indice del vector series los Numseries pero Como guardo todos los elementos generados en otro arreglo del mismo tipo(char) sin usar punteros ?

```
char series[100]
        
for(int i=1;i<100; i++){    
     strcpy(Series, Persona[i].NumSerie );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si los strings que estás definiendo son del tipo char[], **ya son punteros**, no tiene sentido "sin usar punteros". Efectivamente, el strcpy es la solución para copiar el contenido de un char [] a otro.

A lo mejor lo que te están solicitado es que uses std::string. En tal caso la estructura que defines quedaría así:

```
#include <string>

struct Persona{
   std::string numSerie;
   int edad; 
   char sexo; 
   float peso } Personas[100];
```

(he cambiado los plurarles ya que el nombre en singular es más adecuado para referirse a una persona.

Usando string, para copiar basta hacer esto:

```
std::string serie2 = Personas[5].numSerie;
```

No sé si es lo que te piden.